# Natural Boundary of a Series of Holomorphic Functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I have been working on a problem given on an assignment sheet. It reads as follows:

"Consider the series: $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n(z - e^{2 \pi i \alpha n})}$$

Prove that whenever $\alpha$ is an irrational number, this series represents in the domains |z| < 1 and |z| > 1 analytic functions for each of which the circle |z| = 1 is a natural boundary."

I have managed to prove that the series converges in both those domains to an analytic function and that the set: $$ \mathbf{S} = \{ e^{2 \pi i n \alpha} \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \} $$

is dense within the unit circle, so that the singularities of the summands are dense in the unit circle. However, I have been unable to use this in proving the series cannot be analytically extended past the unit circle, and the theorems about natural boundaries we have worked upon in the course thus far have all been about power series. I tried to convert the series into a power series, but to no avail. I would be grateful if anyone shared any ideas.

Comment: analytic continuation at a circle point means on a small arc containing it and that will also contain infinities from the denominators so not possible

Comment: @Conrad Hmm, so the argument is that on the unit circle, the analytic expansion would need to be the same as the series within the disc, by continuity, but that would not be possible since the singularities are dense thereon. But how do functions like 1/(1 - z) minus the geometric series tie into this? Could we not analytically continue the function to whole C by defining it to be 0 everywhere, including at z = 1?

Comment: analytic functions that are $0$ on a small disc are zero everywhere on any connected open set containing that disc; not sure of your question - what the problem above says is that we have an analytic function on the unit disc and an analytic function on the exterior of the unit disc given by the same formula but there is no analytic connexion between them - note that analytic is the keyword as there are of course connections between the two, just they are not analytic

Comment: @Conrad Well, what I was trying to ask was: how can we deduce that the analytic extension is not possible from the singularities of the summands? In the example I gave, 1/(1-z) has an infinity on the circle, but the infinity of the remaining series "cancels it out" in a way, so we can extend it to be zero at z = 1. How can we show something like that won't also hold here?

Comment: not sure what you are asking here - the function goes to infinity in absolute value at every point on the unit circle ( the argument of $e^{it}-r$ is small when $t$ close to $0$ and $0<r<1$ so $1/(e^{it}-r)$ behaves like positive number when one fixes $r$ close to $1$ and lets $t$ accumulate at $1$, so since the coefficients are nonnegative  shows that we cannot have cancellation)

Comment: one can easily show the result (no analytic continuation) when instead of $1/2^n$ one uses any summable series $a_n, \sum |a_n| <\infty$ complex or real by picking $k$ and denoting $z_k=e^{-2\pi \alpha k}$ and then taking a $w$ on the radius ending at $z_k$; if one now writes $f(z)=\sum c_n(z-w)^n$ it is easily seen that the term coming from the $k$ fraction has radius exactly $|1-w|$, while the others have strictly smaller radiuses which easily implies $|1-w|^n |c_n|$ doesn't converge to zero which means that the radius of $f$ at $w$ is $1-w$ so there is no extension at $z_k$ which are dense